Error when trying to setup trigger in neo4j-apoc. "No write operations are allowed directly on this database"
I am trying to set the trigger as given in apoc triggers documentation: https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.trigger/apoc.trigger.install/
I am getting this error:

Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed
Failed to invoke procedure apoc.trigger.install: Caused by:
java.lang.RuntimeException: No write operations are allowed directly
on this database. Writes must pass through the leader. The role of
this server is: FOLLOWER

I am running neo4j 5.20 as a docker container, and have also installed the apoc library. In my neo4j browser, Cluster role is showing as "primary".
Here's the command with which i am starting the container:
docker run --rm --network host -e NEO4J_AUTH=none
     -v $PWD/data:/data
     -v $PWD/apoc.conf:/var/lib/neo4j/conf/apoc.conf
     -v $PWD/plugins:/plugins
     --name neo4j-apoc-new
     -e NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled=true
     -e NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true
     -e NEO4J_apoc_import_file_use__neo4j__config=true
     -e NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS=\[\"apoc\"\]
     neo4j:5.20.0

I found this issue: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/3073, but could't figure out whats wrong.

Please note the error messages that says:  "Writes must pass through the leader. The role of this server is: FOLLOWER". Connect to a server that is a LEADER.

There's only one server of this DB running, how do i turn that into LEADER. Any idea?

To quote the docs:

The apoc.trigger.* procedures are intended to be executed in the
system database, therefore they have to be executed by opening a
system database session.
There are several ways of doing this:

When using Cypher-shell or Neo4j Browser, prefix Cypher queries with
:use system

When using Fabric, prefix Cypher queries with USE system

When using the drivers, open a session directly against the system
database


Moreover, the apoc.trigger procedures accept as first parameter the
name of the database in which the triggers should be installed,
updated, or removed.

So, for example, if you are using the Neo4j Browser, make sure it is in the system database (which Neo4j automatically created) before calling apoc.trigger.install:
:use system
CALL apoc.trigger.install(...)


If you have the project in neo4j desktop, open the project in terminal and follow the below steps to setup the “apoc.trigger.enable=true” in “apoc.conf “file
Steps to Create 'apoc.conf’ via Command Line

Navigate to the conf Directory:
• Use the 'cd' command to navigate to the conf' directory of your Neo4j database.
cmd
<your_directory>\conf

Create the 'apoc.conf’ File:
• Use the 'echo command to create the 'apoc.conf' file with the required configuration.
echo apoc.trigger.enabled=true › apoc.conf
• This command will create a new file named "apoc.conf" in the "conf* directory and write the 'apoc. trigger. enabled=true setting into it.

Verify the File Creation:
• You can verify that the file has been created by listing the contents of the conf directory:


dir
